# Merge two for-loops into one for-loop

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement, primes

The goal of this code is to determine whether a number is prime or not, and if it isn't, prints the numbers that the given number can be divided by.

**My question is:** Is it possible to merge two `for` loops into one `for` loop in the code presented below?

```
num = 224

list1 = []

for i in range(2, num):
    if num % i == 0:
        list1.append(i)

for i in range(2, num):
    if num % i == 0:
        print(num, 'is not prime and can be divided by the following numbers:\n', list1)
        break
else:
    print(num, 'is Prime.')
```

Comment: Did you try it? What happened?

Comment: @roganjosh It's an argument to the message written by the second loop.

Comment: @chepner oops, missed it. The loop still looks wonky. I can't see that they want to print the entire list all those times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on given answers, the best way to redesign the code is this:

```
num = 224

list1 = [i for i in range(2, num) if num % i == 0]

if list1:
    print(num, 'is not prime and can be divided by the following numbers:\n', list1)
else:
    print(num, 'is Prime.')
```

Thank you @matthieu-brucher and @blhsing

Answer (score 1):

Since you've already constructed `list1` with all the divisors in the first loop you can just make use of it in a condition instead of iterating through the same sequence for the second time:

```
for i in range(2, num):
    if num % i == 0:
        list1.append(i)
if list1:
    print(num, 'is not prime and can be divided by the following numbers:\n', list1)
else:
    print(num, 'is Prime.')
```

Answer (score 0):

The second for loop is not needed

```
num = 224

list1 = []

for i in range(2, num):
    if num % i == 0:
        list1.append(i)

if (not list1):
    print(num, 'is Prime.')
else:
    print(num, 'is not prime and can be divided by the following numbers:\n', list1)
```

Comment: You don't need brackets in `if (not list1):`. Also, this answer is practically the same as the one from [@blhsing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52741737/7851470)

Answer (score 0):

This should do it, example with 10 numbers:

```
n = 10

for i in range(2, n + 1):
    divisors = []
    for j in range(2, i):
        if i % j == 0:
            divisors.append(j)
    if divisors:
        print('{} is not prime and can be divided by the following numbers: {}.'.format(i, divisors))
    else:
        print('{} is prime.'.format(i))
```

Output:

```
2 is prime.
3 is prime.
4 is not prime and can be divided by the following numbers: [2].
5 is prime.
6 is not prime and can be divided by the following numbers: [2, 3].
7 is prime.
8 is not prime and can be divided by the following numbers: [2, 4].
9 is not prime and can be divided by the following numbers: [3].
10 is not prime and can be divided by the following numbers: [2, 5].
```